# Sharepoint 2007 workflow doesn't start automatically at new item that created another workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a Task list in Sharepoint 2007 SP2.
For this list I made 4 workflow.
WF1 is check, the task are recurring or not. (This workflow start automatically then new item created)
WF2 is an alerter workflow, that send an email to the user and pause for 1 day.
WF3 is an alerter too, which is activated after the WF2 change the WF3 trigger.
The WF2 and WF3 looping until the Task status will not be Completed.
WF4 is create a new task in this list (with same name) and increase the Start and Due date +1 month.

If the WF4 created a new task the WF1 doesn't start automatically.

Have anybody a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2007 will not allow workflows to loop so I think you may have aproblem in Wf2 or WF3

This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2009/07/13/service-pack-2-prevents-an-on-change-workflow-from-starting-itself.aspx) provides more information about looping workflows.